# Convert dataRowview to dataTable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to convert dataRowview into Datatable:

```
private void Cell_Edit_End(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
        rowBeingEdited = rowView;
    }
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in rowBeingEdited.Row.GetChildRows) {
                dt.ImportRow(row);
            }
```

Can anyone help me to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly convert dataRowview into Datatable as:

```
 DataTable dt = rowBeingEdited.DataView.ToTable();
```

Comment: I was expecting to get the data table `dt` with one row. However i'm receiving all rows in the current view. I mean, if the `DataView` referred by `rowBeingEdited` had four rows, i'm getting all the four rows in `dt`. Maybe i'm missing something. The data view is pointing to a data table with more rows filtered by `DataView.RowFilter`

Comment: I guess the following helps someone.  `DataTable dt = rowBeingEdited.Row.Table.Clone();`  `dt.Rows.Add(rowBeingEdited.Row.ItemArray);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataRow.Table.Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an empty table with the same columns:

```
DataRow[] childRows = rowBeingEdited.Row.GetChildRows("RelationName");
if (childRows.Length > 0)
{
    DataTable tblChildren = childRows[0].Table.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow row in childRows)
        tblChildren.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: @RashmiS: you are using [`DataRow.GetChildRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.getchildrows(v=vs.110).aspx). It is not a property(so your code doesn't compile) and there is no overload without parameter. So i've used one that takes a string.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a filter, this is the right answer

```
datagridview.DataSource.current.DataView.ToTable()
```

I tried all the other solution this not orking so well or it takes a long time